# Joomla Extension Editing

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

How do I  add a field in the contact component of Joomla?
Suppose I want to add two fields:

1. Year
2. Branch

In the default Joomla contact component

Comment: you could take another extensions, e.g. QContacts : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-details/4811

Comment: exactly, why waste time reinventing the wheel!